# a href / router-link inside a clickable tr

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

So, I got a table with `<tr>`s which are clickable. And inside a `<td>` a link:

```html
<tr
  @click="editPlatform(platform.id)"
  v-for="platform in platforms"
  :key="'platform_table_' + platform.id"
>
  <td>{{ platform.id }}</td>
  <td>Many more tds</td>
  <td>
    <router-link
            :to="{ name: 'platformUsers', params: {id: platform.id} }">
    {{ platform.users.length }}
    </router-link>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
methods: {
  editPlatform(id) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'editPlatform', params: { id: id } });
  },
}
```

And the `<router-link>` event seems to bubble through. The url changes to the `platformUsers` for a millisecond but then the `editPlatform(id)` is also triggered and it goes there.

I tried `<router-link @click.native.prevent="editPlatform(platform.id)" ...>` and `style="pointer-events: none;"`on the router-link - but they don't work either.

Any idea beside setting the "@click" on each td - beside the one with the link?

Comment: In my case I wanted to prevent click on the `tr` from a `table` when I clicking in an ' href` without a method. I used `.self` in the ' td` and moved the method from the `tr'  to each `td`. Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838076/how-to-ignore-that-clicking-on-a-td-tag-does-not-automatically-redirect-me-to-an/74465289#74465289

Answer (score 2):

`stop` and `prevent` modifiers aren't the same! This should work

```
 @click.stop="editPlatform(platform.id)"
```

See docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: Great, please mark as solved @bibamann

Comment: already marked as duplicate - but the @click.stop (no = ... needed) needs to be put on the "td" above, not the router-link. otherwise the page reloads and doesn't have the single-page behaviour. 

Maybe not mark it as "duplicate" :D

Comment: Okay, got it thx. Wasn't me who marked as duplicate though. :)